# adjusting top separator inset for first row of SwiftUI List row

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I need to adjust the inset of the list separator that appears at the bottom of the section header, or the top of the first row of the section (depending on how you want to describe it)
I've seen how I can adjust the inset of List row separators, adding something like this to the row:

```
    .alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorLeading) { viewDimensions in
        return 20
    }
```

I've also seen that I can hide the separator associated with the top of the first row, or change its color. But how do I adjust the inset of the top separator? As in the below mockup, I am attempting to move the top separator all the way to the left edge of the screen, while the other list separators retain some inset from the edge.

[image]

The only possible solution that occurs to me at the moment would be to add the section header as a different kind of row instead of as a section, and then to adjust the alignment guide for that pseudo-row, but I am hoping there is a better way. [EDIT: Trying this approach did not work as hoped].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.